# Weka: How to find distince values of an attribute?

Tags: java, weka

Suppose the iris data has 3 unique class values.

```
@ATTRIBUTE class    {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}
```

How can I get these values using the Weka API? The closest I could find is numDistinctValues(), which I currently use as

```
System.out.println(data.numDistinctValues(data.numAttributes()-1));
```

However, this only gives the distinct number of classes i.e. 3. I want to get the actual values, i.e. the class labels "Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica".

We can find distinct class values using the Instances(), by extracting all the class labels corresponding to every instance and then find unique values from them. Is there a direct way to extract this information directly from the dataset description in ARFF format?

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution

```
for (int i=0;i<data.classAttribute().numValues();i++) {
        System.out.println(data.classAttribute().value(i));
    }
```

Basically, we find the number of values in the class attribute and then iterate on that number to find the corresponding values using the value() method.

Answer (score 0):

For numerical attributes, you can use this code to get the range of your data:

```
AttributeStats as = instances.attributeStats(index);
double min = as.numericStats.min;
double max = as.numericStats.max;
```